# Nikon 18-300mm will not mount to body

Tags: lens-mount

My Nikon 18-300mm ED DX suddenly no longer mounts to my D5500. White dots lined up, lens mount/unmount button depressed camera body turned off. I do not want to force the turn for it to click and lock...  I've never had this problem with a lens before.

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Answer (score 7):

I just found the issue, upon closer examination of where on the ring it was not seating, ONE slightly loose screw! Hope this helps someone else!

[image]

Comment: I was just about to post the same solution, so I've added a photo marking the loose screw.

Comment: It’s perfectly fine to accept your own answer.

Comment: @EricS but there is an enforced delay before you are allowed to do so - 48 hours IIRC

Comment: Lol, assuming you are being funny... but if not and I did break a rule.. .lol and I'm sorry ;)

Comment: @TonyaMoon nobody's being funny - that's just how this site works. The site is here to answer your questions, but also to help other people with the same issue. A repository of questions and answers. If there are mutiple answers, and one is _accepted_ as the correct answer, that benefits everyone - easy to spot the correct answer amongst other suggestions. Also, it gives you points, in case you want to grow your score/reputation on the site. Take a look at the [tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Okay, so technically I needed to wait 48 hours to supply the answer because I posted the question. Makes sense now. My apologies, it was not intentional.  GREAT site and service!